# Angular UI-Router (1.x) Change Host Url

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have a requirement from a client to change the web site Url to a subdomain when they enter the checkout section of the site we are developing for them. For example from www.mysite.com to checkout.mysite.com. We are using UI-Router in HTML5 mode and would like to have the router change the Url to the subdomain instead of going to www.mysite.com/checkout. Does anyone know a way that this can be accomplished? I've also tried using pushState but without success. All of the subdomain suggestions I've tried have not worked. Honestly even if I just put a "fake" url that would work fine too. Changing the Url is more of a visual thing instead of actually redirecting to a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

After much review I found that this cannot be done because it is a security issue; even switching to a subdomain (which is what I was trying to do) is not allowed.